# creating DataFramr From list object

Tags: python, pandas

```
dobj = {'reflectivity':pd.Series(np.array(gate_reflectivity)),#,index =list(range(len(gate_reflectivity)))),
        'RainRate':pd.Series(np.array(gate_RainRate)), #,index =list(range(len(mmlits)))),
        'Rainmm':pd.Series(np.array(Rainmm)) #,index =list(range(len(RainRate))))
        }
d = pd.DataFrame(dobj,columns =['reflectivity','RainRate','Rainmm'])
new_file = filenamex[:-2]+'txt'
open(new_file,'w')

np.savetxt(new_file,d,fmt='%10.5f',delimiter = ",",header =['reflectivity','RainRate','Rainmm'])
```

I am getting Error:

```
header = header.replace('\n', '\n' + comments)

AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'replace'
```

please help me

Comment: Please format your code.

Comment: I  am extracting  some variables from .Nc files and writing them in to new file, and giving headers  to understand which parameter  present in which column

Comment: Super, can you add sample of `.Nc` file (3,4 rows)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`to_csv`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html) with parameter `float_format`:

```
import pandas as pd

gate_reflectivity = [0,10.458682222]
gate_RainRate = [2,3.458771111]
Rainmm = [5,32.78542333333]


#if length of list is equal, omit index    
dobj = {'reflectivity':pd.Series(gate_reflectivity),
        'RainRate':pd.Series(gate_RainRate), 
        'Rainmm':pd.Series(Rainmm) 
        }
d = pd.DataFrame(dobj,columns =['reflectivity','RainRate','Rainmm'])
print (d)
   reflectivity  RainRate     Rainmm
0      0.000000  2.000000   5.000000
1     10.458682  3.458771  32.785423

#testing
print (d.to_csv(float_format='%10.5f', index=False))
reflectivity,RainRate,Rainmm
   0.00000,   2.00000,   5.00000
  10.45868,   3.45877,  32.78542

#writing
filenamex = 'aaaaa.Nc'
new_file = filenamex[:-2] + 'txt' 
d.to_csv(new_file, float_format='%10.5f', index=False)
```